# Android App crashes when I edit my comment

Tags: bug, android-app, comment-edits

Whenever I try to edit my comments, the app freezes for 5 seconds and then it  crashes saying "Unfortunately, Stack Exchange has stopped".

I have edited comments before so I think this might be happening in v1.0.34.

Comment: It would be a good idea to state what version of Android you are running..

Comment: I tried it on 1.0.35 and it does work. Try updating to that version (it's the latest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to **`v1.0.35`** the issue is no longer reproducible.  I just updated the app yesterday and found myself that issue is fixed.